# automated Barchart in Excel

Tags: excel, bar-chart

I'd like to automatically create a barchart in Excel from a set of values. Let's say I have the following unordered data in a column:

who?: {the good, the bad, the ugly, the bad, the ugly}

Then I would like to get a barchart that only contains one bar:

```
[ 20% "the good" |        40% "the bad"           |         40% "the ugly"      ]
```

Does anyone know how I could achieve this ? Ideally there would even be a way to add a legend, with the possibility to add another value that has never been named. For instance the legend of the above dataset could look like:

- 20% the good
- 40% the bad
- 40% the ugly
- 0% mac gyver

Any help or pointers in the right direction are very much appreciated
Thanks
mischa

Answer (score 0):

For a project, I once created a dynamic Gantt chart. This might be a solution for you. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9uWmFWUD5c&feature=relmfu

Otherwise, if the "bar" is in increments of 10%, you could just use conditional formatting in the 10 cells...

Comment: It's not exactly what I had in mind, but thanks, I'll give it a go, if I have the occasion... much appreciated!